# Best method to get android contact infos (addressbook) with StorIO

Tags: android, storio

**Usage for:**

I want to show all contacts in on tab and in the other tab I want to show all groups. The user could select multiple contacts or groups.

**Question:**

Which is the best method to get the contact infos from the Android addressbook?

I want to get all person contacts and all groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use StorIOContentResolver for that

```
storIOContentResolver
  .get()
  .cursor() // or listOfObjects()
  .withQuery(...) // Here you need to create a query to retrieve contacts info
  .prepare()
  .executeAsBlocking() // or createObservable()
```